# Passing if block as parameter

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, rust

I'm trying to write a small test program in Rust, and, as almost everything can be an expression in this language, including `if` statements, I wanted to pass an `if-else` block as a parameter to the `println!` macro, like this:

```
println!("{} {} {}", i.name, if v>0 {"owes"} else{"must receive"}, if v<0 {-v} else{v});
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
src/main.rs:34:38: 34:39 error: mismatched types:
 expected `f32`,
    found `_`
(expected f32,
    found integral variable) [E0308]
src/main.rs:34      println!("{} {} {}", i.name, {if v>0 {"owes"} else{"must receive"}}, if v<0 {-v} else{v});
```

And the same error with the other `if-else` block, which I've omitted. As far as I've understood the concept, this should work because this `if-else` blocks are expressions which return the last values in each branch.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem seems to be somewhere else. Copying your code to play.rust-lang.org works fine: http://is.gd/CSsphR

Answer (score 2):

`v` is probably an `f32`, which means the comparison `v>0` has a type error.
Try `v>0.0` and `v<0.0` instead.

Comment: Generally, when I encounter such errors, I usually try to pull apart the statement into simple let-bindings, to make finding the error easier.

Comment: @Veedrac it was, effectively, a type error in the comparison. Thanks for the help.